# subquery returns more than one row error

Tags: mysql, sql, select, correlated-subquery

Okay, there are.. a number.. of questions on SO with the same title, but I couldn't think of how to be more specific.

The reason that this is confusing me is that returning more than one row is a desired effect of (one of) my sub queries

```
SELECT MAX(theCount) FROM
    (SELECT FK_Hour, Count(FK_Hour) As theCount FROM 
        (Select FK_Hour 
        From slottime 
        INNER JOIN time ON slottime.FK_Hour = time.Hour 
        WHERE FK_Hour = 
            (SELECT time.Hour FROM time WHERE time.day=0 )
        ) As C 
        GROUP By FK_Hour
    ) AS counts;
```

I realise that time is a reserved word for MySQL - it is probably something I will have to rectify soon; though I doubt its the problem in this case.

The aim of the query is to select the maximum count of instances of particular hours where day = 0.

[image: MySQL phpmyadmin designer]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is clearly:

```
    WHERE FK_Hour = (SELECT time.Hour FROM time WHERE time.day=0 )
```

The simplest solution is to change `=` to `in`:

```
    WHERE FK_Hour IN (SELECT time.Hour FROM time WHERE time.day=0 )
```

However, you might want to check your data to determine if this is what you really intend.